# Export specific timestamp from WMS-T layer as TIFF (and polygonize it) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, wms-time

I am using the layer: `ecmwf007.fwi` from this server:

```
https://ies-ows.jrc.ec.europa.eu/effis
```

Now this is a wms layer which is time aware. I would like to extract the timestamp for a specific day (lets say the 24th of July 2023) as a raster and then polygonize it within QGIS.

When I export the raster like this:

[image]

using these settings:

[image]

I always get the first layer by what I can tell.
Is there any chance to do that for a specific timestamp?

Comment: why export as a tiff when the service supports tiff as an output

Comment: if you use export as, on a WMS layer you are just exporting what you have already requested, you aren't making another request to the server

Comment: true, but I wanted to polygonize it and thought it might be a good idea haha
I thought the service just offers png

Comment: The legend shows that QGIS is aware that the WMS is time aware.  You can open the TimeController panel to get the data from the time (range) you want from the service